# Split a number into 3 smaller numbers that form a triangle

Tags: algorithms

Given a positive **integer** L (1 <= L < 10000), how many possible solutions to split L into 3 smaller positive **integer** a, b, c
Such that:

- a + b + c = L
- a, b, c form a valid triangle

**Note: The problem ask for the number of possible solutions**

A valid triangle (a, b, c) must meet these conditions:

> a, b, c > 0 && a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a

Comment: One of the ways is `a = b = c = L / 3`

Comment: Are there some extra constraints that you're not telling us? For example, are `L`, `a`, `b` and `c` required to be positive integers?

Comment: This can be written as: Given L find a, b, c such that `a + b + c = L`, `a + b > c`, `a + c > b` and `b + c > a`. Depending on your triangle definition you can replace `>` with `>=`.

Comment: Any type of triangle?

Comment: It isn't too clear what you mean by "how can I". Do you want any arbitrary way? Do you want to characterise every possible way? Do you want to count the number of ways?

Comment: I meant how many ways you can do that. Updated, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @trincot any type of triangle

Comment: Should the numbers be integers only, or ... ? Please be specific.

Comment: For integer sides, see http://oeis.org/A005044

Comment: @trincot, yes, integer

Comment: Are 3,4,5 and 5,4,3 different partitions?

Comment: @n.m. no they are not. I've found the O(n) solution. Looking for anything better (if they do exists)

Comment: Include your solution (and claim that it is O(n)) in your question please.

Comment: Anyway this is a mathematical problem that has very little to do with programming.

Comment: @n.m It **IS** a programming problem at a programming contest :)

Comment: Although there is an O(1) solution, I've never exactly asked for it in my question. There are many solutions varied from O(n^3) to O(n^2) to O(n). This is a really good programming challenge that shows how well you know your stuff

Comment: No, it is a bunch of clueless noobs creating contests filled with math problems that you for some unknown reasons musr answer with a piece of code.

Comment: @n.m It's a variation of an acm-icpc problem not some clueless contests http://acm.tju.edu.cn/toj/showp3845.html . I am sorry if this question is not fitted for this site. I will close it here. Pardon my ignorance

Comment: I mainly use stackoverflow and have very limited knowledge of other stackexchange sites. I didn't even aware of math.stackexchange. Thanks you guys for suggestions, I have flagged a moderator to close this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

```
 a >= b >= c
```

We've got *two* conditions:

```
 a + b + c = L
 a < (b + c)    /* since {a, b, c} is a valid triangle */
```

So we can conclude, that the maximum side `a` should be

```
 L/3 <= a < L/2
```

and `b, c` are *any numbers* in `(0..L/2)` range (both limits excluded) such that `a + b + c = L`. An easy example is `a = b = c = L/3`

**Edit:** since `a` should be taken to be within the `[L/3..L/2)` range, there're *infinitely many* ways to do this (providing that `L > 0`).

**Edit 2**: The number of different triangles which have **integer side lengths** and perimeter `L` is

```
[L * L / 48]              for even L
[(L + 3) * (L + 3) / 48]  for odd L

[...] stands for inter part (floor)
```

see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerTriangle.html for details

implementation (C#):

```
   int count = (L % 2 == 0 ? L * L : (L + 3) * (L + 3)) / 48;
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I meant to count how many ways you could do it

Comment: @rocketspacer: *infinitely* many. Please notice, that `a` you can choose in the *range*, and that's why there're infinitely many ways to get `a`.

Comment: a, b,c are integers... sorry for my silliness...

Comment: positive integers

Comment: @rocketspacer: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerTriangle.html

Comment: I know there is an O(1) solution!!! Finally, Thank you so much!!! It kept bugging me for days

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more specific. Do you mean find a possible solution or find number of possible triangles. If it's just one solution and I'm assuming a,b and c can only be positive integers, One solution if L >= 3 is a = 1, b =1, c= L - 2. If you want to find the number of possible solutions, then I think this is a recursive problem. Number of ways of dividing a number into three parts is the same as number of ways to divide it into two parts and divide one of the parts into two parts. Now the problem is writing a number as a sum of two others. For that we use basic maths. The solutions for a number n is:

n = 1 + (n-1)
   = 2 + (n-2)
      .
      .
      .
Until (n-k) = n/2.
So now that we can divide a number into two parts, use the logic above to divide the number into two parts first then divide it into two other parts. Keep a counter for the number of solutions you arrive at.

Cheers.

Comment: Updated, I mean how many solutions you can find